# iOS Swipe Detection Works Only For 1 UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add swipe detection on a 2 table cells. However, so far the swipe detection only works with one table cell.

Here are parts of my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];
     numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     tableCellTrash = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

     mSwipeRecognizer= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeCell:)];
     [mSwipeRecognizer setDirection:( UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomPlaceCell";
    CustomPlaceCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomPlaceCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [numbers addObject:cell];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:mSwipeRecognizer];
        NSLog(@"Cell");
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)removeCell:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aSwipeGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"Swipe Detected!");
}
```

Anyone know why swipe detection only works for one of cells?

Comment: How many times NSLog(@"Cell") is logged?

Comment: What do you mean by only works for one of the cells? You mean you can only swipe say first cell and no others or you mean you can't swipe starting from cell one and ending in cell two?

Comment: Yes, I could only swipe in the last cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIGestureRecognizer` can be associated only ton a single view. You should set a different gestureRecognizer for each of your cells. You may move the GestureRecognizer creation inside the

```
     if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomPlaceCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [numbers addObject:cell];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeCell:)];
        [swipeRecognizer setDirection:( UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];     

        [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];

        NSLog(@"Cell");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I'll accept it when stackoverflow lets me in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You'd better add gesture in `CustomPlaceCell's` method:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier.
```

Also, you'd better do:

```
[cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:]
```

, instead of cell itself. You'll find a lot of benefits if you do more complicate behavior in reusable cells.